# Error when starting Django React app with npm start: "Invalid options object" ( 'Something is already running on port 5432' )

Tags: reactjs, node.js, django, npm

I have a Django-React application with PostgreSQL/MySQL. The app was working fine, until today I attempted to start my frontend using npm start. This is the first time I've encountered the following prompt:

> Something is already running on port 5432.
> Would you like to run the app on another port instead? » (Y/n)

Opting for 'Y' leads to the subsequent error:

> Would you like to run the app on another port instead? ... yes
> Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
> options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.

I haven't made any recent changes or installations. What should I do ?

I tried to change the start script in the package.json to `"start": "set PORT=3000 && react-scripts start"`, but that didn't work.
Additionally, I deleted node_modules, package-lock.json, and ran `npm install`, but I still got the same error message.

Comment: *”Something is already running on port 5432”* probably a database or something else that receives remote connections. Check active network ports on your OS. If the application running is something that won’t hurt to `kill` then just `kill` it. But if it will, start your application on another port.